# Postbacks redirecting to the default page instead of partial update

Tags: asp.net, .net, postback

I have an asp.net site.
In testing locally - I get my updatepanels working as expected - my loading bar comes up and the items on the page/ in the panel update as expected.

But when moving over to the production IIS server - all postbacks result in a full page refresh as if Im navigating to the homepage?? It all triggers and changes take effect but I end up on the homepage..

When checking the post in fiddler, I see my tests locally post with XMLHttpRequest - but the live site doesnt.
Ive tried every solution I can find, adding a fix to ensure default.aspx is in the forms actions etc but I cannot get the page to update - always it redirects to the homepage and I have to navigate back to teh tabs etc.

Local:

```
POST http://localhost:27051/default.aspx HTTP/1.1
Host: localhost:27051
Connection: keep-alive
Content-Length: 8968
Origin: http://localhost:27051
X-Requested-With: XMLHttpRequest
Cache-Control: no-cache
X-MicrosoftAjax: Delta=true
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.3; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/39.0.2171.71 Safari/537.36
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8
Accept: */*
Referer: http://localhost:27051/
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
Accept-Language: en-GB,en-US;q=0.8,en;q=0.6
Cookie: ASP.NET_SessionId=ylje5kmitgghieqnooqnt4f2; .ASPXFORMSAUTH=B36E4B22A0555C56FFE897F6743FA158102CA5967D527D3048C060993ADC41456E78DDF4EE062C20A249710E99003A3B4B7B0D23D3E42B0F7D3F61A126AB845341EB9A61978FD42BE5759043702BBD2F30B6F32310054974716150BCB6DDCF9DC88DEA6853AE610B177FA4F7E734E6C8D1B6C015BD28EC0F183763E825DF0529
```

Remote:

```
POST http://domainauctionsniper.com/Members/default.aspx HTTP/1.1
Host: domainauctionsniper.com
Connection: keep-alive
Content-Length: 18089
Cache-Control: max-age=0
Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,*/*;q=0.8
Origin: http://domainauctionsniper.com
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.3; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/39.0.2171.71 Safari/537.36
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
Referer: http://domainauctionsniper.com/Members/default.aspx
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
Accept-Language: en-GB,en-US;q=0.8,en;q=0.6
Cookie: test_cookie=1; PHPSESSID=0214e097364f56ae456327357d390395; wp-settings-time-3=1418154370; wp-settings-time-35=1418158914; wordpress_logged_in_6389fffe4da65b9a5fb2d579b3ba1c19=agibson%7C1418415085%7C8bffd7e31d78153f3983e482883f969f; wp-settings-time-36=1418242317; wordpress_test_cookie=WP+Cookie+check; ASP.NET_SessionId=z3um5tef1u5tnykde3uqx14e; .ASPXFORMSAUTH=553AA3EB6D348BF52535F422FAE112B4D86E002B66244D7CF2BF2ED76C520B09E5549E70D28FA3AF10ECB6EA6AF0148E3CF285D2AAA882A68F297AA622E115C2579A37B2489364438BC8D1F8718FCC8087CD21AE8E1D7A7804E1DABCF4AD964F7D0660ECB13D05F431F23115DC5C8D53A1ECE3BFAEB019ACA44686CEAC23DB15
```

Can anyone confirm what needs to be changed to make updatepanels work as they do locally?

Comment: I have found something interesting.
If I set the Members area to be the default site - domainauctionsniper.com - it works as expected, if moved into a folder /Members/ - the postbacks mess up and refresh the whole page.

Can ANYONE explain this?

Answer (score 0):

Finally found it...

I have a rewrite rule on the site for the wordpress install:

```
  <rewrite>
    <rules>
        <rule name="Main Rule" stopProcessing="true">
            <match url=".*" />
            <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll">
                <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" negate="true" />
                <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsDirectory" negate="true" />
                </conditions>
                <action type="Rewrite" url="index.php" />
            </rule>
        </rules>
    </rewrite>
```

This thing is written all over the web to correct wordpress permalinks.
THIS also breaks the navigation of my members area!

Adding the below additional rule corrects the lot.